# Java - constructing multiple objects of a generic class in a static function

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to implement generic class which defines order on objects. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OrderedObject<T> implements Comparable<OrderedObject<T>> {

    private T object;
    private int orderId;

    public OrderedObject(T object, int orderId) {
        this.object = object;
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public T getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public static ArrayList<OrderedObject<T>> defineOrder(ArrayList<T> objects) {
        ArrayList<OrderedObject<T>> orderedObjects = new ArrayList<OrderedObject<T>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
            T object = objects.get(i);
            OrderedObject<T> orderedObject = new OrderedObject<T>(object, i);
            orderedObjects.add(orderedObject);
        }
        return orderedObjects;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(OrderedObject<T> o) {
        return orderId - o.orderId;
    }

}
```

in `defineOrder()` I'm trying to initialize multiple objects of this class at once - I want the order to be defined by positions of generic objects in the array, and this static function would take generic object `T` array, and return `OrderedObject<T>` array. Unfortunately, the code as I wrote it won't compile, it says that the reference to the static field T cannot be made, because T is not static.

Why is T not static? Also, is there a way out of this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type parameter `T` defined on a class is in scope only in non-`static` contexts.  It's not in scope inside `static` methods.

However, you can always declare another type parameter for the `static` method itself.  Note that this `T` is not the same as the class's `T`.  It could be renamed without affecting anything, as long as references to `T` inside the `static` method are also renamed accordingly.

```
public static <T> ArrayList<OrderedObject<T>> defineOrder(ArrayList<T> objects) {
```

[Section 8.1.2 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2) states:

> It is a compile-time error to refer to a type parameter of a generic class C in any of the following:
>
> - the **declaration of a static member** of C (§8.3.1.1, §8.4.3.2, §8.5.1).
> - the declaration of a static member of any type declaration nested within C.
> - a static initializer of C (§8.7), or
> - a static initializer of any class declaration nested within C.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you can't use `T` in a static context is that `T` is defined by an instantiation of this class. Therefore, `T` will not be defined when you are not able to create an instance of this class (i.e, when using a static method). I suggest that you define a new generic (perhaps `K`) for use solely in the context of this static method.

Your new method signature could then look something like this:

```
public static <K> ArrayList<OrderedObject<K>> defineOrder(ArrayList<K> objects)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see a solution to making it static. If you delete the static reference in your function like;

```
public ArrayList<OrderedObject<T>> defineOrder(ArrayList<T> objects) {
```

then it compiles just fine

Comment: You just need to put a type parameter on the method. See rgettman's answer for the syntax.

Comment: But then I would have to create "empty" OrderedObject<T> just to make defineOrder() usable, right? This is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: This may limit the use of the method, where it would have been intended to be used as a static method, rather than an instance method.

Comment: Ah. Misunderstood that part. My apologies.